# Rspec rendering text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I have this Code

```
if @temp_user.save
  sign_in(:user, @temp_user)
  render text: "OK"
else
  render text: render_to_string(:partial => "errors")
end
```

and I try verify with rspec the render "OK"

this is my actual spec:

```
  it "render text OK" do   
    post :create, {:agent => valid_attributes}
    # response.should have_content("OK")
    response.should render_template(:text => "OK")
  end
```

but this spec respond 0 failures always, even when I put "OKI" in place "OK"

anyone have one suggestion for that?

Comment: May be 'describe "render text OK" do' and not 'it "render text OK" do'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using rails 3 or above

```
expect(response.body).to eq "OK"
```

will work

Answer (score 12):

```
response.body.should == "OK"
```

works for me

Comment: In rspec 3 and above it should be as:
`expect(response.body).to eq "OK"`

Answer (score 1):

```
describe "render text OK" do   
  post :create, {:agent => valid_attributes}
  # response.should have_content("OK"
  response.should render_template(:text => "OK")
end
```

Comment: expect(response).to render_template(:text => '')

Comment: @drhenner's suggestion results to `Unknown key: :text. Valid keys are: :layout, :partial, :locals, :count, :file` for me.

Comment: My only point was to use `expect`...  What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: @drhenner answer is from 2012. RSpec changed thier syntax from `should` to `expect`.http://rspec.info/blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax/