# Rspec for render inline: location.reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have the following at the end my controller

```
** some code **
respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render inline: "location.reload();" }
end
```

I have to write an `RSPEC` for the same.

```
 expect(response).to render_template(:**what should be given here?**)
```

Or is there any other method to write RSPEC for the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908547/rspec-rendering-text

Comment: yea, i checked that before posting this question, but didn't get any idea to implement it to my code.

Comment: The answers in the linked post tell you exactly what you need to know. If you look at the `response.body` you'll get the body of the response. That is, everything after the headers. So in your case, you'll get `location.reload();` as the response string and you can compare to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for replies, i came to know that we should specify `xhr` instead of `get/post :method`
so this did the trick,

```
xhr :post, :schedule_message, params, format: :js
expect(response.body).to eq "location.reload();"
```